# Link Above a Div with a Low Z-Index

Tags: html

My situation is this:

I have a div with a z-index of -15. I have a div, within that div, that has a z-index of 15.

I just ran this exact code in jsfiddle, and it worked in jsfiddle but not for me in notepad when I opened it in google chrome.

```css
#contentdiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  z-index: -15;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#link {
  position: absolute;
  width: 143;
  height: 216;
  z-index: 15;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentdiv">
  <div id="link">
    <a href="link.html">Link</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your CSS? `z-index` does not work unless there is also the `position` property

Comment: i can able to click the link

Comment: What you have provided works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4zjne1L1/

Comment: Could it be my browser then? I'm using Google Chrome, and it's not working.

Comment: Its probably something with your full code. I would reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle.net and and provide the fiddle demonstrating your issue (with only the relevant code that causes the issue). Chances are, you have a different (invisible) element on top of your link with a greater z-index.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that changed besides for adding the html and head tags, which isn't valid to have your html elements in the `head` tags.